# On what basis have I split the alphabet into 4 sets?

Tags: english

I have split the 26 letters of the alphabet into 4 sets. Here they are:

Set 1: $F G J L N P Q R S Z$
Set 2: $A M T U V W Y$
Set 3: $B C D E K$
Set 4: $H I O X$

Can you determine on what basis have I split them?

Comment: N, S, Z could form a set of their own.

Comment: @FlorianF I was actually thinking the same, which caused me to hesitate about my answer, until I noticed *what* I was missing with those. But yeah, they should have had their own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess:

> I think you have split them based on symmetry. The first group has no real symmetry, while the second group can be divided by drawing a line from top to bottom. The third group can be splitted by drawing a horizontal line from left to right, and the last group can be divided using either a vertical or horizontal line.

Comment: But N,S, and Z is symmetrical over a point in the middle.

Comment: @Taemyr I know - but they are not symmetrical by drawing a line either horizontally or vertically: Therefore I said that the first group has `no real` symmetry.

Comment: @KevinVoorn What you mean to say is that they have no reflectional symmetry.

Comment: @Otaia Exactly, English is not my native language :3